# Place Drawable on Imageview using PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView:

```
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

I would like to achieve something like this (*Atop* figure)
[image]

`drawable1` is the original ImageView image, `drawable2` is the one I want to place over it:

```
Drawable drawable1 =  AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawable1);
Drawable drawable2 = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, drawable2);

LD layerDrawable = new LD(new Drawable[]{
       drawable1,
       drawable2,
});
imageView.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```

LD class:

```
public class LD extends LayerDrawable
{
    private Paint p = new Paint();

    public LD(Drawable[] layers) {
        super(layers);
        p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        int count = canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);

        for (int i = 0, numberOfLayers = getNumberOfLayers(); i < numberOfLayers; ++i) {
            this.getDrawable(i).draw(canvas);
            canvas.saveLayer(null, p, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
        }
        canvas.restoreToCount(count);

    }
}
```

However this doesn't work, because the image I place over (drawable2) is placed over the whole imageView, not just over the non-transparent contents of the drawable1 image.

How do I achieve Atop figure (placing drawable2 only over the 'filled content' of drawable1)?

Edit:

```
p.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, 0, 0, p);
```

Comment: extent `Drawable` and draw your two `Bitmaps`s inside `draw()` method - the second with `SRC_ATOP`

Comment: please provide example

Comment: what's unclear in drawing two bitmaps?

Comment: they are still both drawn on the whole imageView and I used canvas.drawBitmap to draw them.

Comment: post your code then

Comment: see edit in main post

Comment: try adding `canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);` before your draws, and of course `canvas.restore()` after them

Comment: looks like this did the trick. Thanks